# tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath) vs. tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath()?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

This two methods look very similar and I'm not sure if I understand fully how to know which one to call.

Am I right to assume that

```
tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath)
```

is what the tableView sends to its dataSource while,

```
tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath()
```

is what the controller sends to the tableView?

Answer (score 3):

Let's write these method selectors in the standard Swift way.

The selector `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` is part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. The table view sends this message to its `dataSource` once for each visible row.

The selector `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` is part of the `UITableView` class. You can send this to a table view to ask it for the cell of a **visible** row. If the row is visible, the table view returns the cell. Otherwise, the table view returns nil.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting it. It helped to see them written like you did. Thanks!